# How does Html.DropdownList actually bind?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

So I am in the process of learning MVC/Razor and I can not figure out how this is quite working.

In the Create Method

```
ViewBag.GenreId = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name");
```

I have on the page

```
@Html.DropDownList("GenreId", String.Empty);
```

And this works.  Where I get confused is the difference between the ViewBag and the property of the object

So I can change the first line to

```
ViewBag.x= new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name");
```

and

```
@Html.DropDownList("x", String.Empty);
```

But of course it does not get bound back to the object So what is the proper way to set up a dropdown list for a field when I may not want the list name to be the same name as the object property?

I guess can get the value from the Request.Form object directly but that kind of side-steps the whole point of Model binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dropdownlist helper automatically searches for a select list with the string passed

1. your Model
2. ViewBag
3. TempData

If a selectlist is created, the helper will render a dropdown list with name and id attributes with the same name as the string passed

In the process, the helper assumes that the id and name will be the same as the string passed. Whatever string you pass will populate the name and id attributes of the rendered dropdownlist.

if you use

```
@Html.DropDownList("x", String.Empty);
```

the resulting dropdown list will have name="x" and id="x". Any action method you post to will receive a parameter called "x".

If, on the otherhand, you wanted to differentiate the name of the bound parameter and you selectlist, you could use an overload of DropDownList

```
Html.DropDownList("Genres", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.GenresList)
```

Comment: I get the last statement and I can retrieve `Request.Form["x"]` but is there any Html Helper that says: Use x as the datasource for the dropdown but after selection bind the selectValue to property Y

Comment: If I understand you properly, you can use an overload of Html.DropDownList("Genres", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.GenresList)

Answer (score 1):

I thought viewbag is a dynamic object and in the context of the above question viewbag.x would serve the purpose. I tried setting the following at the controllers end.

```
        Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);
        ViewBag.x = new SelectList(db.Genres, "GenreId", "Name",album.GenreId);
```

and retrieving the values at the Views end with the following and I had no issues.

```
        @Html.DropDownList("x","Please Select a Value")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GenreId)
```